# calling an injected function requires direct dependency of the function dependencies?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, build, dependencies

I have an android app which uses two shared library A,B which I write as well.

The app injects an `OnClickListener` to library A, that calls library B.

Does library A need to depend directly on library B? As it gets the `OnClickListener` as a black box. It will call library B but I assume it gets it from the context of the app that depends on them both.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library A will not depend on Library B if the only thing being passed is an `onClickListener()` regardless of what is inside.

The application will obviously depend on both Library A and Library B.